# How send error message to client when connexion to socket is denied?

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I just use this on my chat exmeple (from http://socket.io/get-started/chat/):

CoffeeScript

```
io.use (socket, next)->
  return next(new Error('401::denied'))
```

JavaScript

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  next(new Error('401::denied'));
});
```

so my connexion socket is always denied. But how can I get the error message `'401::denied'` ?

I need to know the server error message to notificate the client with the good custom message.

Comment: You don't even have a client unless you have an active socket connected to him. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Exactly. If I refuse connexion, how can I know why server is refusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer has more simple than I excepted^^

```
socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```